# How to create a component from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component based on string.

I have few heading sizes

```
const headingLevel = {
  xl: 1,
  large: 2,
  normal: 3,
  small: 4,
  xs: 5
}
```

I determine component like this

```
const heading = `h${headingLevel['xl']}`
```

This should make the heading as `h1`

Based on this

```
<h1 className={combinedClasses} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </h1>
```

if
const heading = `h${headingLevel['large']}`
then

```
<h2 className={combinedClasses} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </h2>
```

There are two ways of doing, first is to use if conditions

```
if (heading === 'h1') {
return <h1 className={combinedClasses} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </h1>
}
```

or to create a map for the same. I was wondering if there is a better way to do?

Something like this

```
<[heading] className={combinedClasses} {...rest}>   {children} </[heading]>
```

Where heading could be `h1` , `h2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a component that takes heading level and children as props and returns specified heading element using `React.createElement` function

```js
const headingLevel = {
  xl: 1,
  large: 2,
  normal: 3,
  small: 4,
  xs: 5
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
     <Heading headingLevel={`h${headingLevel["xl"]}`}>
       Extra large heading
     </Heading>
     <Heading headingLevel={`h${headingLevel["normal"]}`}>
       Normal heading
     </Heading>
    </div>
  );
}

function Heading({ headingLevel, children }) {
  return React.createElement(headingLevel, null, children);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capitalize the variable name so JSX knows you're referring to a component.

```
const Heading = `h${headingLevel['xl']}`;
return (
  <Heading>Hello world</Heading>
);
```